# Unable to create Database for content providers

Tags: android

My application has a database that has to be exposed to global search. I have the sqlite database as a raw file. I am trying to copy the database file to the databases directory in my project but it throws a FileNotFoundException. I am guessing that this is a permissions issue.

My application is similar to the Searchable dictionary but the problem is that since I have around 2000 records, it is taking around 15-30 seconds to populate the database. I also have to way to tell the user that the data is loading. So I just decided to use the sqlite database which I can copy to the databases directory of my project in the onCreate method of my databasehelper class.[extends SqliteOpenHelper].

Now I use the same method to copy my actual application database and it works fine. This may be because they are running in the same process.

How can I copy my database to the databases dir or where to I need to copy it to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant? Not possible to copy the database to that location or is it not possible to show some sort of loading dialog? -Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to get "access" to the database.  Although, if you root the phone, it may be possible, but I don't know anything about rooting a phone, and unless you want to require a rooted phone then I believe it is "impossible"